# How to record sound from playback device and reproduce on recording device?

Tags: c#, naudio

I want to capture sounds from my speakers and play them in my recording device `Line 1` using `NAudio` or some other API.

How can I do that?

I can list `WaveIn` and `WaveOut` devices with

```
public void ListDevices()
{
    Console.WriteLine(" WaveIn devices ");

    int waveInDevices = WaveInEvent.DeviceCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < waveInDevices; i++)
    {
        WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveInEvent.GetCapabilities(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Device {0}: {1}, {2} channels", i, deviceInfo.ProductName, deviceInfo.Channels);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" WaveOut devices ");

    int waveOutDevices = WaveOut.DeviceCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < waveOutDevices; i++)
    {
        WaveOutCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Device {0}: {1}, {2} channels", i, deviceInfo.ProductName, deviceInfo.Channels);
    }
}
```

But they are the exact opposite of what I want. I was able to record from my microphone and listen on my speakers, but I want to do the opposite. How?

Comment: May i suggest running a cable from your audio out to your audio in ports?

Comment: @Rafael I am using a `wireless stereo headset` and I want the sound playing on this device to play on `Line 1` recording device. Something very similar to what `Virtual Sound Cable` does.

Comment: It makes sense now, if you mean this one: http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm, it seems that it creates its own virtual devices, so any sound sent to any of this virtual devices it's played into another input virtual device, however, i'm not sure that this can be done with just a library/API.